# How many average onions are there per pound?

Tags: vegetables

How many onions are there on average per pound assuming they are average size?

I have tried figuring out by number of onions per cup and number of cups per pound, but when counting it with tally marks I just couldn't get it to be the right number.

Comment: The tomato question has pretty much already been answered here, if you take average to be medium: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43542/what-size-are-small-medium-and-large-tomatoes so I'm going to edit this to just include the onion question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The USDA thinks](http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3077?qlookup=11282&max=25&man=&lfacet=&new=1) a medium onion is 2.5" diameter and weighs 110g, so that'd be about four per pound. (For completeness, they also say a large onion is 150g and a small is 70g.)

In general if you want to look up information like this, just google "onion nutrition", and there'll be relevant results plus a knowledge panel on the right with a nutrition table, a drop-down to pick serving size, and a link at the bottom to the USDA page that everyone's getting their data from.

Comment: or you can go to the produce converter website and they will tell you certain things like how much of an ingredient you need the way that you want it and how many of medium, large, and small there are per pound. They use medium or average size in their numbers for the amount of an ingredient you want the way you want it.

Comment: @caters If you want to answer a question, post an answer, not a comment.

Comment: that "or" there should have told you that I was commenting on his answer not answering it myself.

Comment: @caters I understand that you posted it as a comment. That doesn't mean it *should've* been a comment, though. If you say something which amounts to an answer, it should be posted as an answer.